# mysql daily count ifnull zero

Tags: mysql

I have a query like,

```
SELECT count(*), cdate 
FROM tabl 
GROUP BY YEAR(cdate), MONTH(cdate), DAY(cdate);
```

this is returning the daily counts but only for days that exist in the column cdate, I want all days for the last X amount of days including those with zero count.  How can I achieve this?

cdate format is %Y-%m-%d

Comment: you can't without extra work. mysql cannot/will not create rows/records out of thin air. if you want the no-records-exist days listed, you need to provide them - e.g. a temp table that contains the dates for every date in the range you want, that you can join against.

Answer (score 0):

This query will only return the data that is available in the table `tabl`.

To get information for all the days, you will need some table which contains the date rows. Usually, I would use a date dimension table and join it with `tabl` as below:

```
SELECT ISNULL(count(1), 0), cdate 
FROM DimDate D
LEFT JOIN tabl T ON D.Date = T.cdate
GROUP BY YEAR(D.Date), MONTH(D.Date), DAY(D.Date);
```

Comment: Do you use MySQL or MariaDB. With MariaDB it is not necessary a extra table

Comment: Using MySQL.  I think I got it, so to get last X amount of days I just use t.cdate BETWEEN?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numbers table, then you can use that.  Otherwise, you can use a trick.  Something like this:

```
select date_sub(curdate, 1 - interval n.n day) as thedate,
       count(t.cdate)
from (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
      from tabl
      limit 100
     ) n left join
     tabl t
     on t.cdate = date_sub(curdate, 1 - interval n.n day)
group by n.n;
```

This basically uses your existing table to count back "n" days (in this case 100).  You can adjust the `limit` clause to get any number of days that you want, assuming the table is big enough.